# Android Linkify lower cases the URL

Tags: android, linkify

I have a URL with some Upper case letters like `http://myserver.com/apps/DroidApp.apk`

When I passed this url to Android [Linkify](http://developer.android.guohai.org/resources/articles/wikinotes-linkify.html), the resulting link's letter case changed to `http://myserver.com/apps/droidapp.apk`

```
TextView upgradeLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.upgradeNow);
upgradeLink.setText("Download now.");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("Download");
String scheme = "http://myserver.com/apps/DroidApp.apk+"?action=";
Log.e(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"Schema URL "+scheme); // printed http://myserver.com/apps/DroidApp.apk?action=
Linkify.addLinks(upgradeLink, pattern, scheme);
```

How can I over come this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Internally, `Linkify` is calling

```
public static final boolean addLinks(Spannable s, Pattern p, String scheme, null, null)
```

Check the [code for that method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.0_r1/android/text/util/Linkify.java#Linkify.addLinks%28android.widget.TextView%2Cjava.util.regex.Pattern%2Cjava.lang.String%29):

```
public static final boolean addLinks(Spannable s, Pattern p,
        String scheme, MatchFilter matchFilter,
        TransformFilter transformFilter) {
    boolean hasMatches = false;
    String prefix = (scheme == null) ? "" : scheme.toLowerCase(); // <-- here is the problem!
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

    while (m.find()) {
        int start = m.start();
        int end = m.end();
        boolean allowed = true;

        if (matchFilter != null) {
            allowed = matchFilter.acceptMatch(s, start, end);
        }

        if (allowed) {
            String url = makeUrl(m.group(0), new String[] { prefix },
                                 m, transformFilter);

            applyLink(url, start, end, s);
            hasMatches = true;
        }
    }

    return hasMatches;
}
```

Extend `Linkify` and override this method, removing the `scheme.toLowerCase()` bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can add helper function to change the urls modified by Linkify

```
/***
   * hyperlinks @toThis to @linkThis in the given @textView
***/
fun addLinks(textView: TextView, linkThis: String, toThis: String) {
   val pattern = Pattern.compile(linkThis, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
   android.text.util.Linkify.addLinks(textView, pattern, toThis, { s, start, end -> true }, { match, url -> "" })
  //Maintain url case
  val spanText = textView.text
  if(spanText !is Spannable) return // no need to process since there are no URLSpans
      val matcher = pattern.matcher(linkThis)
      while (matcher.find()) {
      val span = spanText.getSpans(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), URLSpan::class.java).first()
      val spanFlags = spanText.getSpanFlags(span)
      spanText.removeSpan(span) //remove modified url added by linkify
      spanText.setSpan(URLSpan(toThis), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), spanFlags) //add the original url
      }
      textView.text = spanText
   }
```